# Do you have to draw an omen/event/item card as soon as you enter the room?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In Betrayal at House on the Hill, when you enter a new room and it has a symbol on it indicating to draw a card, do you have to draw that card as the first thing you do? Or can I play an item, or do another action before drawing the card?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would you want to do this? To what benefit?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I can't remember to be honest, it came up the other night when we were playing the Frankenstein scenario. It might have been to heal using the medpack before an event was drawn?

Comment: Maybe play it on a case by case basis. I think if they've read the card already - then it would be inappropriate to heal. If they've forgotten to heal before moving and have yet to receive a card, it would be up to your group to rewind and allow it or not.

Comment: Was wondering if I could use a Crystal Ball after the room is discovered, but before the item or event card is drawn. Crystal Ball would be an overpowered item then, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

You are able to use items and other actions mid-move, but as soon as you discover a room, your movement immediately ends and you must draw an Event/Item/Omen card before you are able to take any other action.

From the rules ([which can be downloaded here](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/HOTH_Rules.zip)) on page 6:

> You can perform actions (such as using an item or attacking) in the middle of your movement. However, whenever a game effect makes you draw a card for any reason, you must stop moving for the rest of your turn.

and

> When your explorer enters a doorway, and there isn’t a room on the other side, look at the top tile on the room stack. .... Then move into that room. You have discovered it.

and then on page 10

> The first time you discover a room with a symbol, you must end your move
>   in that room and draw the appropriate card.

Comment: I saw all those rules in the book myself, but none of them preclude drawing the event card after playing an item. Just because you stop moving doesnt mean your turn is over (also in the rules when it's describing your actions) and your last quote doesn't say you have to draw a card immediately upon discovery. Just that you have to stop moving.

Comment: It is never 100% explicitly stated, but based on the above rules quotes (especially the second and third), when you discover a room you stop moving and draw the associated card. It does not say you stop moving, then sometime later in your turn you draw the card. There is another quote at the bottom of page 10 that also supports this, saying that after you draw the card you can continue taking actions.